# Workflow email integration

Tags: designer-workflow

I have a workflow where a specific set of users will receive emails when there's an attachment for the list item. Its working fine but there users are getting too many emails.

Lets say there are 20 items with attachments so users are getting 20 emails. So is there any way to integrate the information in one single mail and send it once in a day?

I have similar requirement for both SharePoint 2010 and 2013 versions.

Please suggest

Comment: Any ideas about how it can be done?

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I don't know if there is a simpler way to do that.

I would do the following:

- create an hidden list
- have the workflow post "task" items to the list. Have the task contain all the info you need to actually perform the task (sending the mail)
- use a timer job with daily schedule to process all the tasks in batch. After you are done delete the task (or leave them there if you need history).

would that be an option for you?